# How to make selenium webdriver to wait for iframe to load completely if it is having only src attribute

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

*How to make selenium webdriver to wait for iframe to load completely if it is having only src attribute.*
     I am trying to create a test case where an iframe containing the form element loads from a different source, while switching to this iframe, the content of this iframe is not available and thus failing the test. So how i can make Webdriver to wait till iframe loads completely.

Comment: you need to wait for the content to load, so use explicit wait until the content get loaded and perform action.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I am doing it in my code:

```
By by = By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'')]");

    try
    {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(by));

     //your actions on iframe here
```

}

Comment: will it wait for frame to load completely? Because in my case, frame takes long time to load almost 15-20 sec of time.. Thanks for reply.

Comment: since this frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt takes string as argument, do i have to re-define or re-write this method for passing By Object.

Comment: "wait" here is basically   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200), and 200 seconds is time up till what it will keep looking for the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the frame using `driver.switchTo().frame(..)` then, wait for the element to load inside the frame. 
Use either Implicit Wait or Explicit Wait for doing it, better to go for explicit waits.

Comment: Hi rishi, i have kept implicit time to 30 sec and so there is no use of taking explicit time, as frame loads within 30 sec of time. My question to you is will it wait for frame to load completely. I am already using  ]